# Regex multiline

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to highlight everything between '<%' and '%>' with a richtextbox. 
(for example, putting every javascript code in blue)

Every other highlighting function works so far, but these are singleline highlights. 
I've found the right code to do multilines, but I think my regex is wrong at this point.

Any suggestions?

Used regex:

> `@"\<\%(.*?)\%\>"`

example code:

```
textextextext
<%
this is javascript code
%>
textextextextextextextext
```

desired result:

```
<% 
this is javascript code 
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add DOTALL(`s`) modifier and also you don't need to escape `<`,`%` symbols in the regex. `(?s)` modifier makes dot in the regex to match even newline character also.

```
(?s)<%.*?%>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pZ9vI5/4)

C# code would be,

```
String input = @"textextextext
<%
this is javascript code
%>
textextextextextextextext";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?s)<%.*?%>");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/mPTBNJ)